# Bootstrap Masonry is not detect the correct height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-masonry

I"m using the masonry plugin for my site,

but unfortantly when you enter the page and the page load its not caculate the correct height the page needed,

and there is a need to refresh.
how can i solve it?

http://halomli.co.il/index.php?page=gallery&galleryId=3

Answer (score 0):

I figure out what was the problem, 
I add the height to the image and it fixed.

```
$("div.post-box").each(function(){
    $(this).find("img").height($(this).height()); 
});
```